# NullPointerException после jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(...)

Tags: java, android, logcat

```all
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at   ru.network.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:121)
        at ru.network.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:94)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)     at        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Выдает такую ошибку. Что делать, 
MainActivity.java:

```java
package ru.network;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText  login , pass;
private Button mSubmit, mRegister;


private static String Data;

public static void NmSN(String data){
    Data = data;
}

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://nw.pe.hu/authmb.php";



// JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "ifAuth";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // setup input fields
    login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    // setup buttons
    mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

    // register listeners
    mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stubs
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.login:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = login.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                    params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            success = 1;
            if (success == 1) {

                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                // save login data

                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                Editor edit = sp.edit();
                edit.putString("username", username);
                edit.commit();
                new AttemptGetData().execute(json.getString("ID"));
                JSONObject jsone = new JSONObject(Data);
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileAct.class);
                i.putExtra("ID", json.getString("ID"));
                i.putExtra("name", jsone.getString("name"));
                i.putExtra("surname", jsone.getString("surname"));
                i.putExtra("avatar", jsone.getString("avatar"));
                finish();
                startActivity(i);



                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Неверный логин и\"или пароль!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted

        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: на 121 строке NPE. что на 121 строке?

Comment: @metalurgus  Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

Comment: значит jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                    params); возвращает null

Answer (score 2):

Ваш `JSONParser` возвращает `null`, необходимо добавить соответствующую проверку перед использованием результата, который возвращает функция `jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",params);`.

А вообще, стоит самому научится читать стектрейс и выявлять причину ошибки.